# freeswitch change frequency

Tags: audio, frequency, freeswitch, pbx

Im back with another questions about freeswitch.
The default sending frequency from freeswitch is 8000. So when i record an piece of the stream the frequency of the mp3 (or wav) is also 8000. What i need is a higher frequency.
All that i found is an variable:

```
<action application="set" data="record_sample_rate=44100" />
```

I added it to the extension but it doesn't change anything. (44100 is not my must have frequency. But higher than 8000 where great). Maybe if this is not possible, do you guys thinks that change the frequency over python is a great idea?

Hope somebody knows a trick to realize that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use "sox" now for resampling the audio file. You can execute the commandline tool in the script. When somebody knows another function or method in freeswitch for sending in another frequency please tell me

Answer (score 0):

Freeswitch always uses the same frequency for recording as the one of the channel that is recorded. This way, it is the most economical way to do recording without extra real-time work for the CPU.

You can upsample the wav file later, with specialized audio conversion tools in low priority.

And hey, this question belongs to serverfault, not to stackoverflow.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer. Can i change the frequency of the channel? Maybe i ask this question on serverfault?

Comment: the frequency of a channel is defined by the codec. G722, for example, works at 16KHz, and Opus is at 48Khz. So, it's really depending on the codec that is negotiated between two SIP parties. You can easily find me on skype: ssinyagin